# Force rsync to share CPU time?

Tags: rsync, cpu-usage

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

I've been using Linux as my main OS for over a year now, but I'm still puzzled by many things.

I'm just discovering the power of `rsync`. It's powerful stuff but it is (apparently) absolutely terrible about sharing CPU. When an `rsync` command is running (at least one run by me) the whole of the rest of my system becomes pretty much unusable.

Is there anything to be done about this? Is it possible to require it to pause execution or share CPU time, as just about every application does? It's funny because I also use `rclone`, Timeshift and Backintime, which all appear to use `rsync`... but none of these causes these unavailability events. This gives me hope that this beast can perhaps be tamed.

I even find that if I kill an `rsync` process (and observe what is going on with `top`), somehow the laggy behaviour seems to persist. Often I find myself having to reboot after running an `rsync` command.

**Edit**
A typical command (although some of my experiments were indeed src and dest on the same partition, which I didn't realise was problematic) might be this:

```
sudo rsync -zavh --delete --log-file=/home/mike/log/rsync.txt '/media/mike/W10 D drive/My Documents' '/media/veracrypt_MyBook_MyDocs'
```

As it happens this particular case is a mounted Veracrypt volume on an external HD. As mentioned in my comment, things seems to have improved. Will continue experimenting.

Comment: Any particular copy with `rsync` that makes your system sluggish? When a backup program uses `rsync`, there's probably not much to copy if it's doing incremental backups. If you make a fresh copy of a huge directory, then you'd compete for disk I/O (but probably not CPU).

Comment: If lagginess persists it might be that everything got swapped out, or that all disk buffers got used. Try suspending the rsync with Control-Z every few seconds after you start it; continue with `fg`; observe in another window the system stats. You can also use `ionice --class 3 rsync ...` to try reducing disk i/o. Do you have many hard-linked or sparse files? Are src and dest on the same filesystem? Add more info to your post, including the command you use.

Comment: Thanks both. Since these were experiments I did, with one or two, make the mistake of backing up to the same partition. I also happened to look at a page in Firefox which complained of a nasty (JS) script which had got tied in knots. I just did an experiment without FF open, and backing up to a different partition and the results seem less problematic. I shall also look up fg and ionice.  Also adding my command to the question...

Comment: Veracrypt explains why you see a lot of cpu usage, I suppose. If you are interested in encrypting incremental rsync backups (to a non-veracrypt device or server), check out `duplicity` and its gui `dejadup`. Also for rsync backups, look up options `-H -S -X` to see whether you should be using them too.

Comment: @meuh In fact only some of my (on-going) experiments relate to Veracrypt. Thanks very much for the expert tips though, I shall certainly check those things out. In fact I just backed up (rsync) an 11 GB partition to a 20 GB VC volume on an external hard drive and it performed pretty well, although no doubt there are performance costs.